# How to cast a string to a specific format in Kotlin?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, format

In normal language, like C#, its simple:

```
long test = 110119225603;
string dateFormat = test.ToString("##:##:## ##:##:##");
Console.WriteLine(dateFormat); // 11:01:19 22:56:03
```

So, how to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: `In normal language, like C#, its simple:` what is a `normal` language ?

Comment: Write a custom extension function...

Comment: use SimpleDateFormat class to get date with specific format

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the possibility of extending an existing class in Kotlin and write a small extension function that does what you want:

```
// extend Long with a suitable function
fun Long.toFormattedString(format: String): String {
    // get the Long as String in order to be able to iterate it
    val s = this.toString()
    // provide a variable for the index
    var i = 0
    // create an empty result String
    var sb: String = ""

    // go through the pattern String
    for (c in format) {
        // replace # with the current cipher
        if (c == '#') {
            sb += s.get(i)
            // increment the counter
            i++
        } else {
            // for every other char in the pattern, just add that char
            sb += c
        }
    }

    return sb
}

// try it in a main function
fun main() {
    // provide an input and a pattern
    val l: Long = 110119225603
    val p = "##:##:## ##:##:##"
    // print the result of the extension function
    print(l.toFormattedString(p))
}
```

This ouputs

```
11:01:19 22:56:03
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for myself in this way.
Bar-code contains date and time.

```
val word = "0030512100221113162055"
val time: String = word.substring(word.length - 6, word.length)
val formatedTime = time.replace("..(?!$)".toRegex(), "$0:")

val date: String = word.substring(word.length - 12, word.length - 6)
val formatedDate = date.replace("..(?!$)".toRegex(), "$0:")
val finalResult = formatedDate + " " + formatedTime

println(last)
```

p.s. Dont be so triggered, i don't see a simple answer to a simple problem